# LWC - How to set current time when having date already? (Converting Date to DateTime)

Tags: lightning-web-components, datetime, date

I need to convert a Date to DateTime and display the value in LWC. I would like to calculate this on LWC's side not Apex.

I already got the logic and calculated for Date. Now I want to append the time to it but the time must be **current time**

For eg: We have Dec 6 2023 as a Date value. How can I make it to Dec 5 2023 + recent time?

I've tried the method setHours(), setMinutes() but it returns the Tue Dec 5 2023 and time.

Thank you so much.

Comment: What do you mean by "recent time" and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`lightning-formatted-date-time`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-date-time/documentation) component. This component allows you to format the date and time according to the user's locale and preferences. You can also specify the time zone, the hour format, and the date parts to display.

To append the current time to a Date value, you can use the JavaScript **Date** object to create a new **DateTime** value from the **Date** value.

For example, if you have a Date value stored in a variable called **dateValue**, you can do something like this:

```
let dateTimeValue = new Date(dateValue);
let currentTime = new Date();
dateTimeValue.setHours(currentTime.getHours());
dateTimeValue.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes());
dateTimeValue.setSeconds(currentTime.getSeconds());
```

Now you have a **DateTime** value that has the same date as the original Date value, but the current time as well. You can then pass this value to the `lightning-formatted-date-time` component and display it in your LWC.

For example, you can use something like this in your HTML template:

```
<lightning-formatted-date-time value={dateTimeValue} year="numeric" month="numeric" day="numeric" hour="2-digit" minute="2-digit" hour12="true"></lightning-formatted-date-time>
```

This will display the date and time in a format like **12/6/2023 4:35 PM**, depending on the user's locale and settings. You can customize the format by changing the attributes of the component.